# how to transfer multiples files and data to API in one request with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-file-upload

i have a angularjs form with data (name,surname,adress...) and multiple file upload. 
I use this to manage fileupload : https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

But what i want is to fill my form, choose files and just submit the form.
I don't want to have to download files before submit the form.

but my files are uploaded after my data

how can i do for submit my form, upload files on server and if it's ok continue the treatment?

i tried this in my controller :

```
this.submit= function() {
    fileStore.uploader.uploadAll();
    //rest of my code
}
```

i also tried with `OncompleteAll()` function.

Comment: To upload multiple files and data with one POST request, use the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: thanks, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

i found solution to upload files and save data just after :

```js
 this.submit= function() {

            $scope.uploader.uploadAll();
            $scope.uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
               // the code to save data
            };
}
```